# Inequality relating to discrepancy of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Given that $\Delta {x_n} \downarrow 0$   $(n \to \infty )$ and $n\times \Delta {x_n} \to \infty$ $(n \to \infty )$ (which will mean that ${x_n}$ is uniformly distributed mod 1) I need to prove $${D_n} \le k(\frac{{x_n}}{n}+\frac{1}{n \Delta{x_n}})$$.

I also know that for any sequence ${x_n}$ $\frac{1}{N} \le{D_N} \le 1$. I think I almost understand why this inequality is true because I notice that $k(\frac{{x_n}}{n}+\frac{1}{n \Delta{x_n}}) \to 0$ $(n \to \infty )$. But I think this isn't enough because the left hand side also depends on n and as n tends to 0 ${D_n} \to 0$.

Could you give some hints on how to shoe this? Thank you in advance.